# Clarrification on quadratic running time

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have code like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        f(); // constant operation
    }
}
```

The number of times f would execute appear to be:

n+n+(n-1)+(n-2)+(n-3)+...+2+1+0 = (n*n)-n = n^2-n

If we drop the low-order term (-n), The big O would be O(n^2).

Is this all correct?

Comment: n^2-n, drop then n, its O(n^2) now

Comment: Sorry, o(n) is a typo.

Comment: @hnefatl I edited the code, it should be i <= n. n+n is not a typo.

Comment: @morbidCode Then it should be `(n+1) + n + (n-1) + ...`, no?

Comment: @hnefatl why is that?

Comment: @morbidCode There are `n+1` distinct values in between `0` and `n` inclusive, and when `i = n`, `j` will go from `0` to `n` inclusive.

Comment: @hnefatl yes you're right! Thanks! Maybe you can put that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your derived complexity is correct, but there are two errors in your equation for the number of times the loops run for:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        f(); // constant operation
    }
}
```

There are `n + 1` distinct values in the inclusive range `0` to `n`, so your inner loop will run for `i + 1` iterations. As such, your formula should be:

```
(n + 1) + n + (n - 1) + ... + 1 + 0 = n(n + 1)/2 = (n^2 + n)/2
```

As it's an [arithmetic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum). This is still `O(n^2)`, as `n^2` grows faster than `n` and the constant `1/2` doesn't matter.